# SQL query into option form

Tags: php, sql-server-2014

I have a PHP code to get info from my Microsoft SQL server 2014, but it isnt working, the page it self works fine since it pops up as it should when i comment out the PHP code, but as soon as the PHP code isnt commented out, its just all white, so im assuming problem with the PHP code. I have to get the results from the query out into a drop down menu.

i use this code:

```
$servername = "VCCSQL03";
$username = "forecast";
$password = "Telefon2";
$dbname = "Forecast";

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$dbname, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(!$conn) {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Check connection
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_BrandProduct");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['Brand_ProductID']."' name='".$row['Brand_ProductName']."'</option>";
    }
} else {
    echo "";
}
sqlsrv_close();
```

Comment: Could you maybe show what code you're commenting out, and show what happens when it is commented out and when it isn't?

Comment: First step is to enable an error reporting and displaying of errors. I have no clue how you want to fix an error you don't know about. Error message is the most important information. Even PHP super-ninja needs it.

Comment: Also next time format your code properly, please. Nobody would read such mess you posted. If you want others to dedicate their time to help you, you have to dedicate your time to ask a proper question. And formatting is important part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you do not have an open and closed `select` tag, and your `option` tags   was missing a `>` to close it properly. Try the below revision, assuming connection is established on the page properly then this should work.

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$dbname, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

         if(!$conn) {
          //// Check connection
             echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
                   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
               }

     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_BrandProduct"); 
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   // output data of each row
    echo "<select name='products'>";
           while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo "<option value='".$row['Brand_ProductID']."'>$row['Brand_ProductName']</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";

    } else {
echo ""; } sqlsrv_close(); ?>
```

Comment: its working now, thank you for help :)

It also turned out my user didnt have the correct access to the database, so that was also a problem, but its all working now.